# Comparing objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects

```
let pets = [
    {type: 'dog', name: 'Bernie'},
    {type: 'cat', name: 'Bonnie'},
    {type: 'lizard', name: 'heartache'},
    {type: 'dog', name: 'spinach'}
];
```

I'm writing a function that takes in this array and returns true if all the types are the same and false if not.

Here is what i've tried:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < pets.length; i++) {
        if (pets[i].type != pets[i + 1].type) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I thought this would work. Isn't this iterating through the loop and comparing the first object's type with the next?

I've also tried

```
for(let i = 0;i < pets.length;i++){
      let petOne = pet[i];
      let petNext = pet[i+1];
      if(petOne[i].type != petNext[i].type){
        return false;
      }else{
        return true;
 }
}
```

I feel like I'm close. How would I go about comparing the pet types and returning true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return true` only after the loop finishes, else you're returning inside the first iteration regardless.

You also need to make sure that the item after the one you're iterating over exists before comparing, so don't iterate to the very end, iterate to one before the very end.

```
for (let i = 0; i < pets.length - 1; i++) {
    if (pets[i].type != pets[i + 1].type) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Another approach:

```
const { type } = pets[0];
return pets.every(p => p.type === type);
```

Comment: The `for` loop will throw an `undefined` exception if all type matches. Perhaps you should start with `i=1` and then have the comparison as `pets[i-1].type != pets[i-].type`.

Comment: better 
```return !pets.find(p => p.type != type)```

Comment: @zb' an [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) should be more proper in this case.

Comment: @ryeballar semantic only, you need boolean and negative match, so anyway it will do the same :) I wantend to point, that we not need to search rest of array if we have match already

Comment: nice. No need for that else statement. Thank you gang.

Comment: @zb' `.every` doesn't search the rest of the array. `.every(condition)` is an exact mirror of `.some(nnot(condition))`  - both stop when the predicate passed in returns a value that makes it senseless to continue. `false` will stop an `.every`, while `true` will stop a `some`.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, thanks, so not need to change anything :)